# If my web server certificate expires with a ClickOnce application, what happens?

Tags: c#, ssl, iis-7, clickonce, web-deployment

I have a ClickOnce application where the web server certificate is about to expire.

I need to clarify whether all the certificate expiration questions and comments about programs not working and needing to be uninstalled/reinstalled are from the CODE signing cert expiring or the IIS WEB cert expiring?

Would I be right in saying that if the web server cert expires, the only issue is that users who download from the publicly available website will get an untrusted publisher prompt, they say yes and then it works from then on?

Or will it flat out not work as the package is specifying https and it can't use https if the web server cert has expired?

Any assistance greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

server certificate has nothing to do with the CODE SIGNING certificate you used for your clickonce application. So you are correct - users who will open webpage to download the installer will see "invalid certificate" message from the browser. But after they download the app, it will install just fine.

Please note - i assume you used timestamp server when you were signing your clickonce app. Otherwise, your signed clickonce app will expire when your code signing certificate expires. But again - that's a side note and it has nothing to do with the web server certificate.

Comment: Thanks, that's a relief! Re timestamp server for code signing app, yes that is in place and the code signing cert is current.